# Implement concatenative inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, mixins, prototypal-inheritance

Is it ppssible to implement a concatenative inheritance or at least mixins in C++?

It feels like it is impossible to do in C++, but I cannot prove it.

Thank you.

Comment: Of course that's possible. Just look at what the `operator<<()` for `std::ostream` does. It's used ubiquitously.

Comment: c++ is rich with [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).   I take it that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-heart-soul-of-prototypal-oo-concatenative-inheritance-a3b64cb27819):

> Concatenative inheritance is the process of combining the properties
>   of one or more source objects into a new destination object.

#### Are we speaking of class inheritance ?

This is the basic way public inheritance works in C++.  Thanks to multiple inheritance, you can even combine several base classes.

There might be some constraints however (e.g. name conflicts between different sources have to be addressed, depending on use case you might need virtual functions, and there might be the need to create explicitly a combined constructors).

#### Or is inheritance from instantiated objects meant ?

If it's really about objects and not classes, the story is different. You cannot clone and combine object of random type with each other, since C++ is a strongly typed language.

But first, let's correct the misleading wording.  It's not really about concatenative inheritance, since inheritance is for classes.  It's rather "concatenative prototyping", since you create new objects by taking over values and behaviors of existing objects.

To realize some kind of "concatenative prototyping" in C++, you therefore need to design it, based on the principle of composition, using a set of well defined "concatenable" (i.e. composable) base classes. This can be achieved, using the [prototype design pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/prototype-pattern.html) together with the [entity-component-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) architecture.

#### What's the purpose

You are currently looking for this kind of construct, probably because you used it heavily in a dynamically typed language.

So keep in mind the [popular quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) (Mark Twain ? Maslow ? ):

> If you have a hammer in your hand, every problem looks like nails

So the question is what you are really looking for and what problem you intend to solve. IMHO, it cannot be excluded that other idioms could be more suitable in the C++ world to achieve the same objective.